# Massive latency spikes only when playing a game?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, performance

Please let me know if this isn't the correct site to post this question.

So I recently starting having an issue where everyone in Overwatch would stop moving for half a second, and then rubberband to where they should be. I narrowed it down to significant latency spikes to my router, but this is *only* happening when I play Overwatch.

The following graph shows the latency problem (highlighted green is where I'm playing Overwatch, x-axis is time since I started monitoring in seconds)

[image]

Notice how the upload rate (bytes out) is fairly constant but has several spikes that roughly correlate with the computer-to-router latency. This stops immediately after I close the game.

The part of the graph after the green highlight is just me browsing the web, and when the bytes in (download) goes up is when I start watching a Youtube video. The latency doesn't spike nearly as often when watching a video as when playing Overwatch.

My best guess is that it's something to do with the upload causing high latency, but it appears to only be Overwatch that's affected, nothing else.

Here are my hardware specs:

Intel AC9260 Wifi

AMD Ryzen 5 2600

Windows 10 21H2

Here's a list of what I've tried:

1. I've installed the most recent WiFi driver directly from Intel's site, didn't work
2. I removed my side panel to improve cooling, as well as turned down the transmit power (I assumed it was overheating), didn't help
3. I've tried using Netlimiter 4 to prioritize Overwatch's process for network traffic, didn't help

EDIT:

Here are my more specific networking hardware specs:

I'm currently using a 5Ghz connection with a WiFi range extender, along with a cable internet connection. My router and modem are separate devices, but I've never had an issue with the modem before.

Before you ask, no I cannot test with an ethernet connection, hence why I'm using a range extender.

Comment: Your home network equipment matters too, not just your PC. Edit your question to include your home network details including AP, router, modem (note: the preceding three roles may all be handled by the same box), broadband type, and service level.

Comment: @Spiff Nothing has changed with regards to home router, modem, broadband type and service level. I'm using an AP/Router combo, separate modem and a cable connection, I'm not sure what you mean by "Service level". I'll update my original question with more info.

Comment: By "service level", I meant what speed of broadband service you're paying for, according to your account paperwork. Is it 1gbps down, 10 mbps up? Or 50 mbps down, 5mbps up? The reason I asked for your modem information is that certain models of cable modems are based on a faulty Intel chipset known to have latency spike problems when dealing with lots of small packets, which is what game traffic usually looks like. But if I don't know which cable modem you have, I can't look it up on the list of known-bad modems.

Comment: I get my exact speed, 30Mbps down and 5Mbps up. I've never had an issue with the WiFi adapter/modem combo before, this issue appeared seemingly out of nowhere recently. There have been no hardware changes that could've prompted this problem.

Comment: DOCSIS is a shared medium, so if, say, your neighbors are doing more uploading, your modem may need to queue upstream packets more often than it did before, making a latent queueing bug more obvious. "I get high latency when gaming through my cable modem" is the classic symptom of the Intel Puma 6 chipset bug, so it's the first possibility you need to eliminate.

Comment: Ok but my hardware has not changed whatsoever. All the hardware has been working perfectly fine for about one or two months, until this came out of nowhere. So unless the bug magically appeared despite no firmware updates, I highly doubt it's the modem. The only way it could be hardware-related is if my WiFi adapter is starting to fail, which is what I'm trying to diagnose.

Comment: The initial symptom of a failing Wi-Fi card is a loss of wireless connection or intermittent connection. None of this is happening, so hardware seems less likely to me. Can you manage to test this when booting in Safe Mode with Network?

Comment: @harrymc Since this only happens in a single game, I doubt I could test it in safe-mode easily. The WiFi adapter is fairly new (Probably bought it a few months back), so could it really be failing so early?

Comment: An adapter only failing for one game doesn't sound right. I would go for software, and Safe Mode with Network will disable all third-party software. Hopefully the Windows-generic driver will manage to work for your network adapter.

Comment: Have you tried Safe Mode with Network?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a router or modem QoS ("Quality of Service" or simply known as network usage priority) issue. I don't know which one you have, but some of them lets you configure that.

Also, other people talked about your connection speed, but your ping is what matters the most (oubviously).

Do note that some updates for the router/modem, game or DRM may mess up everything.

Answer (score 0):

[You might need to install a ping analyser so that we see a more detailed report](https://www.pingplotter.com/download)

The Link will take you to ping analyser tool called [PingPlotter](https://www.pingplotter.com/download).

How do I use PingPlotter?
To send a PingPlotter file, please follow the steps below:

1. Please let us know your WAN IP address (Wide Area Network Internet Protocol) and the name of your ISP (Internet Service Provider).
   An easy way to get your WAN IP address is to visit http://ip4.me/ and record the IP address (the numbers under "You are connecting with an IPv4 Address of:" )
2. Close all open applications including torrents, DC-clients, ICQ, Web Browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome, Opera and the like), and Mail clients, etc...as these can interfere with the connection test results. Also turn off all other computers in your local network.
3. Install PingPlotter on your computer. You can get download it from the following link:
   http://www.pingplotter.com/downloads/pingplotter_install.exe
4. Launch PingPlotter and maximize the window.
   The trace interval should be set to 1 seconds.Please type or copy the IP of your server in the "Enter target name or IP" field.Now click the green start icon

*Note:
Make sure you remove the the port and the : (column) from the IP address.
For example if your server's IP and port is 46.249.47.12:2513 in our game server control panel, then the IP would be: 46.249.47.12.*

5. Right click on the columns and enable the checks for errors, minimum, maximum and average latency. (All  items inside the redboxes, from the screenshot above, should be checked)
6. Now please double click on each of the bottom hops, so that each hop has it's own graph.
7. Please allow Pingplotter to run for at least 15 minutes, while you experience network problems. Problems can be spotted by periods with lots of packet loss or high latency. These can be visualized in the PingPlotter graphs as red blocks or spikes and steep spikes in the latency.

Finally, please click "file" (in the upper left hand of you screen), then "export sample set > all data."
Also do a save as image, make sure the save as type for the image is PNG.

[Source: Elitegameservers.com](https://www.elitegameservers.net/clientarea/knowledgebase/21/Analyzing-network-issues-which-can-cause-lag-ping-spikes-and-packet-loss-.html)